# Resque Workers not working on the right DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I have Resque set to use database 6 like this:

```
Resque.redis = "localhost:6779:6"
```

I then started my resque as follows:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test PIDFILE=./resque.pid QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

When I check workers, there are none:

```
pry(main)> Resque.redis = "localhost:6779:6"
=> "localhost:6779:6"
pry(main)> Resque.workers
=> []
```

But when I check on database 0, I can see it is there:

```
pry(main)> Resque.redis = "localhost:6779:0"
=> "localhost:6379:0"
pry(main)> Resque.workers
=> [#<Worker ub40:6352:*>]
```

How do I make my worker use a different database?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working. It turns out there was resque-scheduler rake task that was overriding Resque's redis setter.

Comment: And how did you change the resque-scheduler rake task in order to prevent this override?